# ECSliding ViewController Navigation Hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm using ECSlidingViewController (See [Documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ECSlidingViewController/2.0.2/)) to achieve the sliding menu function.

## What I intend to do

Here's the list of my `ViewControllers`

- SlidingMenu
- View Controller A (embedded in `Navigation Controller`)
- View Controller B1
- View Controller B2
- View Controller C

The navigation sequence should like this:

```
A----------B1
    |      |-------C 
    |
    |------B2
```

Also inside `SlidingMenu`, there are options to go to `ViewController` B1 or `ViewController` B2 directly.

The effect I want to achieve is: when using `SlidingMenu` to navigate to `ViewController B1` or `ViewController B2`, the `Back` button on the navigation bar should take the view back to their parent view. (i.e, B1/B2 should back to A).

## Problem

When the app is running, **only after using** the `ECSlidingViewController` to navigate to B1/B2, the navigation bar on B1/B2 is missing and there's no "Back" button to get to their parent view (i.e. view A).

Please note: If B1/B2 is navigated via view A, then the navigation bar is fine and well displayed.

So, how can I achieve the desired effect? Is there any method to push the correct navigation stack in it rather than just replace the `topViewController`?

## Related Code

Inside the SlidingMenu view, there are two buttons for navigating to B1 and B2

```
- (IBAction)B1Pressed:(id)sender {
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B1"];
    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)B2Pressed:(id)sender {
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B2"];
    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope I can use these screenshots to elaborate the problem clearly:

Sliding Menu:

[image]

View A (top left button is to open the Sliding Menu)

[image]

View B1 (if navigate from View A, the navigation bar and "back" button are well displayed)

[image]

View B1 (if navigate from Sliding Menu, the navigation bar and "back" button are disappeared)

[image]

Comment: Hey man Im sure you already got this on lock, but have you check to see in the storyboard under the view controller's inspector tab, and see if Top Bar is set to none?

Comment: @TomTesticool hi mate, I just checked the storyboard, and the Top Bar (View A, B1/B2, C) is set to "Inferred"

Comment: Try changing it to Navigation Opaque

Comment: The Simulated Metrics will have no effect at runtime.  They are for design purposes only.

Comment: @Nick hi nick, I mean the navigation bar on B1/B2 is missing only after navigating to it via the SlidingMenu. If the B1/B2 is navigated via View A, then the nav bar is fine.

Comment: Show the code you use which causes the problem.

Comment: @Wain I've update some code and some screenshots. I think the screenshots can tell the problem well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is your problem:

```
- (IBAction)B1Pressed:(id)sender {
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B1"];
    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
```

If you think about what this is doing it's destroying the centre navigation controller and the A controller that it contains (and anything else in the stack).

What you should be doing, instead of calling `topViewController =`, is to get the `viewControllers` from the navigation controller (which is the `topViewController`) and edit the array contents (and reset it into the navigation controller.

In this way you maintain the navigation and root view controller (A) while inserting your new controller into the stack.

Comment: Hi Wain, thx for the help. Here's my understanding:

`NSArray *stack = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:overViewController, tableViewController, newItemViewController, nil];`

`navController.viewControllers = stack;`

Then I'll set the `navController` as `topViewController` for Sliding Menu to use. Is that correct?

Comment: The nav controller is already top view controller, so just reset the sliding controller to center. And you can put whatever you want into the stack so that's fine.